# Joda DateTime library shows incorrect results

Tags: api, date, jodatime

Joda APIs seem to be returning incorrect results. I have 2 dates to be compared. One of them is in the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss and another is in the format YYYYMMDD. Having read posts about the former not being a standard format, I converted it to the same format as the later (YYYYMMDD). However, the results are still unacceptable. I tried both DateTimeFormatterBuilder and also manually substringed the date to the required format. Below is my code. I understand that daysBetween is making a diff of days of the month and probably I should be using some other API to actually get the difference. However, the bottom line is, in this example, date 1 is shown to be greater than date 2, which is wrong. 
FYI, I am using nscala-time just as a wrapper from the scala code. It is internally calling Joda APIs. Is there anything wrong with my code or is it a bug in the library?

Note: The results are correct when the year is different. So the comparison seems to be comparing just the year portion.

Below is the code:

```
package util
import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports._
import com.github.nscala_time.time.StaticDateTime
import com.github.nscala_time.time.StaticLocalDateTime
    //import org.joda.time.*;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder
import org.joda.time.DateTimeComparator;
import org.joda.time.Months
import org.joda.time.Days

object dateFormats {
    val YYYYMMDD = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("YYYYMMDD")
        //val YYYYMMDDHHMISS = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
    val YYYYMMDDHHMISS = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendYear(4, 4).appendLiteral('-').appendMonthOfYear(2).appendLiteral('-').appendDayOfMonth(2).appendLiteral(' ').appendHourOfDay(2).appendLiteral(':').appendMinuteOfHour(2).appendLiteral(':').appendSecondOfMinute(2).toFormatter()
}

object TestJoda {

    def toDateTime(dtString: String, fmt: DateTimeFormatter): DateTime = {
        //println("date is " + dtString + " Format is " + fmt)
        fmt.parseDateTime(dtString)
    }

    def toEpoch(dtString: String, fmt: DateTimeFormatter): Long =
        toDateTime(dtString, fmt).getMillis()

    def monthsBetween(FromDT: String, fmt1: DateTimeFormatter, ToDT: String, fmt2: DateTimeFormatter): Int =
        Months.monthsBetween(toDateTime(FromDT, fmt1), toDateTime(ToDT, fmt2)).getMonths

    def daysBetween(FromDT: String, fmt1: DateTimeFormatter, ToDT: String, fmt2: DateTimeFormatter): Int =
        Days.daysBetween(toDateTime(FromDT, fmt1), toDateTime(ToDT, fmt2)).getDays

    def compareDT(FromDT: String, fmt1: DateTimeFormatter, ToDT: String, fmt2: DateTimeFormatter): Int =
        DateTimeComparator.getInstance().compare(toDateTime(FromDT, fmt1), toDateTime(ToDT, fmt2))


    def isGreaterDT(FromDT: String, fmt1: DateTimeFormatter, ToDT: String, fmt2: DateTimeFormatter): Boolean = {
        compareDT(FromDT, fmt1, ToDT, fmt2) match {
            case -1 | 0 => false
            case 1 => true
        }
    }

    def convertToYYYYMMDD( in : String): String = {
        val out = in .substring(0, 4) + in .substring(5, 7) + in .substring(8, 10)
        println("YYYY =" + in .substring(0, 4) + "MM =" + in .substring(5, 7) + "DD =" + in .substring(8, 10))
        out
    }

    def testJoda() = {
        // val d1 = "2005-04-17 00:00:00"
        val d1 = convertToYYYYMMDD("2005-04-17 00:00:00")
        val d2 = "20051107"
            //val COMPUTE_DATE_DIFF = isGreaterDT(d1,(dateFormats.YYYYMMDDHHMISS),d2,(dateFormats.YYYYMMDD))  
        val COMPUTE_DATE_DIFF = isGreaterDT(d1, (dateFormats.YYYYMMDD), d2, (dateFormats.YYYYMMDD))
        println("As per Joda " + d1 + " is greater than " + d2 + " is " + COMPUTE_DATE_DIFF)
        val dbtn = daysBetween(d2, (dateFormats.YYYYMMDD), d1, (dateFormats.YYYYMMDD))
        println("days between are" + dbtn)
            //val d1e = toEpoch(d1,dateFormats.YYYYMMDDHHMISS)
        val d1e = toEpoch(d1, dateFormats.YYYYMMDD)
        println("d1 to epoch is" + d1e)
        val d2e = toEpoch(d2, dateFormats.YYYYMMDD)
        println("d2 to epoch is" + d2e)
    }


    def main(x: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val returned = testJoda()
        println(returned)
    }

}
```

The output is:

```
YYYY =2005MM =04DD =17
As per Joda 20050417 is greater than 20051107 is true
days between are10
d1 to epoch is1105948800000
d2 to epoch is1105084800000
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the code. The day format specifier needs to be 'dd' instead of DD. That resolved the error